# Assume that the domain of the predicates is the set of all plants. Let P(x): “x is poisonous” and Q(x): “Jeff has eaten x”.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I just started a discrete mathematics course (required for my degree apparently) and I am struggling to say the least.

Question:
Assume that the domain of the predicates is the set of all plants. Let P(x): “x is poisonous” and Q(x): “Jeff has eaten x”.

Translate: Some plants are poisonous.

Proposed answer is: $(\exists x)~(P(x)\wedge Q(x))$

> [image: 1]

Comment: Added the link as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll walk you through translating the putative answer; you'll see that it does not translate the sentence you would like, but I'll leave the actual translation to you.

So $\exists x$: "there exists $x$" then there is an implicit "such that" followed by
$(P(x)\wedge Q(x))$: remember the $\wedge$ means "and", so this means $P(x)$ *and* $Q(x)$ are both true for the $x$ that is given to us by $\exists x$. $P(x)$ means "$x$ is poisonous," and $Q(x)$ means "Jeff has eaten $x$".

So, all together, the sentence reads in (mostly English), "There exists some plant $x$, such that $x$ is poisonous and Jeff has eaten $x$." In other words, "Jeff has eaten [or has had the experience of eating] a poisonous plant."